# Post from Google Keep to Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-keep

Is there a way to post (publish) a note from Google Keep to Google+ (sure I don't want to do copy+paste)?

I tried to find support for Google Keep, but I couldn't find it easily to ask them directly.

If there's no way, they should definitely do it.

Comment: I haven't used Keep but here is a Google Keep community on Google+. Perhaps people there can help you.
https://plus.google.com/communities/112416874311247567378

Comment: For what it's worth, it's trivially easy to do from Android.

Comment: @AlE. Indeed. Now I see they've added it in some of the latest versions. It wasn't there at the time of asking question ;)

Answer (score 2):

At this time, the web app of Google Keep doesn't have a button to share notes somewhere else, but there is a one to copy the note to a new Google document. From there you could share the document using Google+, Twitter, Facebook, and to get the URL to share the document using other tools.

From [Create Google Docs from Keep notes on the web - Keep Help](https://support.google.com/keep#6191106)

> Create Google Docs from Keep notes on the web Do more with your ideas
>   by copying notes into a Google Doc, where you can expand, edit, and
>   polish your ideas.
>
> To copy one note into a Google Doc:
>
> - Hover over the note you want to add and click the Menu [image: Menu].
> - Select “Copy to Google Doc.”
>
> To copy multiple notes into a Google Doc:
>
> 1. Hover over each note you want to add.
> 2. For each note, click the check mark [image: Check Mark].
> 3. In the gray action bar at the top, click the Menu [image: Menu].
> 4. Select “Copy to Google Doc.”